# WPF style not applied to all controls

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

Problem: Not all of my custom checkboxes are displayed in the same way and it is unclear to me, why.

I have a custom WPF `CheckBox` of which I generate instances at runtime.

The custom `CheckBox`:

```
public class CheckBoxQuickSelect : System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox
{
    public string Description { get; }

    public CheckBoxQuickSelect(string description)
        : base()
    {
        Description = description;

        Margin = new Win.Thickness(10, 0, 0, 0);
        VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center;
        VerticalContentAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center;
        Style = (System.Windows.Style)this.FindResource("MySettingsCheckBoxStyle");
    }
}
```

The part where I add the checkboxes at runtime:

```
foreach (string abbreviation in Helper.TreeSpecies.Keys)
{
    CheckBoxQuickSelect cb = new CheckBoxQuickSelect(abbreviation);
    cb.Name = Helper.MakeValidXmlName("checkBoxTreeSpecies_" + abbreviation);
    cb.Content = abbreviation.Replace("_", "__") + ": " + Helper.TreeSpecies[abbreviation][1];
    cb.IsChecked = Helper.TreeSpeciesQuickSelect.Contains(abbreviation);
    stackPanelTreeSpecies.Children.Add(cb);
}
```

The associated style in `App.xaml`:

```
<Style TargetType="CheckBox" x:Key="MySettingsCheckBoxStyle">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
</Style>
```

There is also a general `CheckBox` style earlier in `App.xaml` (but it doesn't change anything if I comment that out):

```
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type CheckBox}}" TargetType="CheckBox">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{DynamicResource StandardFontSize}" />
</Style>
```

The problem now is: Only the checkboxes with an underscore in their abbreviations get displayed correctly:

[image: Display of custom checkboxes]

Why is that? What can I do to make all boxes look the same?

Comment: As a note, instead of creating UI elements in code behind you should consider using an ItemsControl with a regular CheckBox in its ItemTemplate. Assign or bind its ItemsSource property to a collection of view model item objects with a string and a bool property for the Content and the IsChecked property of the CheckBox. See [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview) for how to start.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the `Style` property of your custom control at runtime in the constuctor, you should define a default `Style` for the control in a resource dictinonary called `generic.xaml` that is located inside a dictionary called `themes` at the root of the project/assembly where the custom control is defined:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CheckBoxQuickSelect">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
</Style>
```

You should then add a static constructor to the custom control class where the default value of the `DefaultStyleKey` property is set:

```
static CustomWindow()
{    
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CheckBoxQuickSelect),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CheckBoxQuickSelect)));
}
```

This should ensure that the default appearance is always applied by default.

Comment: I added the Style to App.xaml instead of this: `<Style TargetType="CheckBox" x:Key="MySettingsCheckBoxStyle">     <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" /> </Style>`
But it yielded the same results. Could you please point me to how exactly create and integrate a generic.xaml? I'm quite new to WPF.

Comment: btw: There is a bracket missing and I can't edit it because it's just one character:
`"{x:Type local:CheckBoxQuickSelect}"`

Comment: You just add a folder called "themes" to your project and then you add a resource dictionary called "generic.xaml" in this folder where you put the default `Style`. These names are by convention. Don't change them.

Comment: That's exactly what I did. Unfortunately, all checkboxes are now back to the old font size defined in App.xaml (`<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type CheckBox}}" TargetType="CheckBox">(...)`). 
What bugs me most is that WHEN I see any effect, it just applies on the checkboxes containing an underscore. I don't get it.

Comment: Crazy: If I add an underscore to every checkboxes' content, the style from App.xaml applies. If I remove it, the style won't apply.